# WPF Usercontrol inside Windows forms not displaying Bitmapframe propertly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have writen a WPF Usercontrol and i use this user control inside Windows Forms application that shows some Thumbnails.

If i use the same Usercontrol, with exactly the same source code, in WPF native application instead Windows Forms application i can see most 'good looking' thumbnails.

Some image to explain better:

Left: Windows forms app with WPF User control

Right: Windows WPF app with the same User control

(not enought rep for direct post image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8JWK.jpg

How can i fix the Thumbnail's in the Windows forms application?

Comment: Are you using an ElementHost? The picture in row 1 look the same; Row 2 left looks like row 3 right; row 3 left looks like row 2 right. Can you show some code?

Comment: i just uploaded two pics with out "jpg compression": http://i.imgur.com/cRALpKO.png and "zoomed": http://i.imgur.com/xT41hfl.png As you can see, WPF (right app) performs like a "gaussian" or some kind of effect on thumbnails. Yes. I'm using an ElementHost in the Windows forms app.